# XPath: Will setting explicit attribute id improve test performance (speed)

Tags: html, xml, xpath, junit

I have been doing some unit testing and as part of testing the XML scripts locate HTML elements with their Xpath.

I've been told by other testers that including an explicit id such as `[@id="IDName"]` will improve performance because it will allow the application to find the element more quickly.

Is that true, or is that a myth?

Just as an example, these are a few Xpaths that I'm dealing with:

**XPATH without IDs:**

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody//tr
```

**XPath with IDs:**

```
//body[@id= "body"]/div[@id= "wrapper"]/div[@id= "MainContent"]/div[@id="Grid"]/div[@id="DataTableContainer"]/div/table/thead
```

Will Java really be able to find the second element faster than the first?

Comment: You may want to do `/html/body[@id="body"]/...`, `//`, a.k.a `/descendant-or-self::node()/` has a cost

Comment: Have you tried measuring it?

Comment: @MatthewFarwell I haven't.  I didn't know if a tool like that existed.

Comment: @pault. Thanks Paul.  Makes sense and will take note of that.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the XPath processor you are using.

Measure it and see.

Using the id() function is more likely to give you fast access than using a predicate, but this depends on it being a DTD-defined ID attribute.

If you want to be sure of indexed access, use XSLT and the key() function.